# the type java.io.FilterOutputstream cannot be resolved. error

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm new to coding. while creating a simple class, I got this error and somehow, many of my previous java projects on Eclipse that worked fine before got the same error (and some new errors). now most of my codes have red cross on them, how can I fixed it.

the type java.io.FilterOutputstream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from a required .class file; **It says on the top of the driver classes**

UPDATE:
-I tried Project> Clean... and it resolved the problem for most files, but not all of them.

-I have the jdk.14 and its library installed.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the JVM is missing.

1. Check Menu: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs
   You should have some versions installed there.
   If not, install a JDK for development, and optionally JREs.
   [image]
2. Check the project's setting: Right-Click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries
   If there is no Java entry, on the right side, click "Add Library" -> JRE System Library to have the default ones shown.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks. I checked and I had the jdk.14 installed, and its library in the library. I tried Project> Clean... and it resolved the problem it most files, but not all of them.

Comment: And which class still cannot be found?

Comment: Sometimes, when you move files/classes into other folders/packages, the imports might not get updated. In Eclipse, you can simply press Ctrl+o to fix that. If the errors are still there, go to the top of the class file, unfold the imports, and check for viability. Or in the line with the compiler error, press Ctrl+1 to show the quick-fix window, that might suggest importing classes or adjusting the referenced libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the project from ellipse and then added it again...that resolved my error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30423522)